# Regular Expression to find string in Expect buffer

Tags: regex, string, scripting, tcl, expect

I'm trying to find a regex that works to match a string of escape characters (an Expect response, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988811/expect-get-variable-from-screen-region-based-on-row-and-column)) and a six digit number (with alpha-numeric first character).

Here's the whole string I need to identify:

```
\r\n\u001b[1;14HX76196
```

Ultimately I need to extract the string:

```
X76196
```

Here's what I have already:

```
interact {
        #...
        #...
        #this expression does not identify the screen location
        #I need to find "\r\n\u001b[1;14H" AND "([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})[0-9]{5}$"
        #This regex was what I was using before.
        -nobuffer -re {^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})?[0-9]{5}$} {
                set number $interact_out(0,string)
        }
```

I need to identify the escape characters to to verify that it is a field in that screen region.   So I need a regex that includes that first portion, but the backslashes are confusing me...

Also once I have the full string in the $number variable, how do I isolate just the number in another variable in Tcl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a few things with some more digging.  First of all I wasn't looking at the output of the program but the input of the user. I needed to add the "-o" flag to look at the program output.  I also shortened the regex to just the necessary part.

The regex example from **@rikh** led me to look at why his or my own regex was failing, and that was due to the fact that I wasn't looking at the output but the input.  So the original regex that I tried wasn't at fault but the data being looked at (missing the "-o" flag)

Here's the complete answer to my problem.

```
interact {
#...
    -o -nobuffer -re {(\[1;14H[a-zA-Z0-9]{1})[0-9]{5}} {
            #get number in place
            set numraw $interact_out(0,string)
            #get just number out
            set num [string range $numraw 6 11] 
            #switch to lowercase
            set num [string tolower $num]
            send_user "  stored number: $num"
    }   
}
```

I'm a **noob with Expect and Tcl** so if any of this doesn't make sense or if you have any more insights into the interact flags, please set me straight.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the number at the end, then this should be enough...

```
[0-9]{6}
```

**Update with new information**

Assuming \n is a newline character, rather than a literal \ followed by a literal n, you can do this...

```
\r\n\u001B\[1;14H(X[0-9]{5})
```

Comment: This regex is in an Expect script that searches the response in an SSH session.  I need the regex to match the entire string \r\n\u001b[1;14HX76196.   The "\r\n\u001b[1;14H" part will always be the same. The "X76196" part will always be a different number.

Comment: I edited my question to define it a little better.  There's more to this than just obtaining the number itself.

Comment: I've updated my answer to match. The brackets will let you get just the Xxxxxx part of the string from the rest of it.