# Expect - How can I perform multiple regular expression matches in one interact loop?

Tags: regex, linux, scripting, tcl, expect

I'm trying to perform multiple regular expression matches on the same screen output, during one interact session.  With the following code I'm getting the error message: **"cannot use -o more than once"**

Ultimately I want to extract several small data variables from each screen of output, using several regular expressions as detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007321/regular-expression-to-find-string-in-expect-buffer).  Is what I'm trying to do possible, if so what is the correct syntax?

```
interact {
    #...
    #... actions during interact loop to perform with variables extracted
    #...

        #variable extraction from output ------------------------------------
        -o -nobuffer -re {(\[1;14H[a-zA-Z0-9]{1})[0-9]{5}} {
                #get po number
                set poraw $interact_out(0,string)
                #get just po out
                set po [string range $poraw 6 11] 
                #switch to lowercase
                set po [string tolower $po]
                #send_user "  stored po: $po"
        }   

        #get cost from po detail
        #ex. 001b[14;27H    20.1900
        -o -nobuffer -re {(\[14\;27H)[0-9]{0-6}\.{1}[0-9]{4}} {
                set pocost $interact_out(0,string)
                send_user "  stored po cost: $pocost"
        } 
}
```

**EDIT:**
So the code that worked looks like this:

```
interact {
    #...

    -o
        -nobuffer -re {(\[1;14H[a-zA-Z0-9]{1})[0-9]{5}} {
                #get po number
                set poraw $interact_out(0,string)
                #get just po out
                set po [string range $poraw 6 11] 
                #switch to lowercase
                set po [string tolower $po]
        }   

        #get cost from po detail
        #ex. 001b[14;27H    20.1900
        -nobuffer -re {(\[14\;27H) *[0-9]{0,6}\.{1}[0-9]{4}} {
                set pocostraw $interact_out(0,string)
                set pocosttrim [string range $pocostraw 7 17]
                set pocost [string trimleft $pocosttrim ]
                send_user "  stored po cost: $pocost"
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man expect`, section about `interact`:

> The `-o` flag causes **any following** key-body pairs to be applied to the output of the current process.  This can be useful, for example,  when  dealing  with  hosts              that send unwanted characters during a telnet session. [emphasis mine]

So it seems that the `-o` changes the behavior from where it appears till the end of the `interact` block. Thus, it makes kind of sense that it can appear only once.

The solution is now obvious: put all the *output* expressions together at the end of the `interact` and add the `-o` just before the first one.

Comment: Does this mean I could have a 
-o { -re { #regex here } -re { #regex here } } (key-body pair) with the regex nested?  I just tried that and it failed to run the -re {} section.

Comment: If I don't nest the -re {} sections withing the -o {} but just place them after, my session fails with this error message: "couldn't compile regular expression pattern: invalid repetition count(s)
"

Comment: @jjclarkson - You should _not_ add braces to the -o option, because syntactically is just another option to `interact` (if you do, then all the text inside the braces will be a big string to be matched!). The unrelated "invalid repetition count" error is because "{0-6}" is indeed an invalid repetition count. It should probably be "{0,6}".

Comment: Great this explained that very well.